# Forces on the Palm Tree in Baahubali 2

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

I'm working on a project for physics class where we are asked to analyze the physics of a movie. I chose [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwS2KlxKXZ8) scene (2:00) from the movie [Baahubali 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4849438/). I was wondering if the palm tree works like a spring with $F = -kx.$ If so, what is displacement? I can't think of how the forces would interact here. This also led me to wonder about springy doorstops. Should I look at this like a simple harmonic motion problem? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Indian superhero movie physics certainly takes the mickey out of American superhero movie physics. For small displacements one can model a flexible beam like a spring, for large ones, not so much. If you want to see what it takes to do your student project "right", here is a link to a paper that does an analysis of a beam with large displacement: http://web.mit.edu/kjb/www/Publications_Prior_to_1998/Large_Displacement_Analysis_of_Three-Dimensional_Beam_Structures.pdf.